# Compare Column Values by Array

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I'm stuck. 
I have a pandas dataframe with j columns, each column containing 1000 values, each column represents a day.  I have another array of individual values, each corresponding to expected values for each day.

I would like to find out how many values in each column are greater than the value of the **previous** day.

```
DF:


D1  D2  D3 
5   6   9
10  2   1 
3   9   2 

Array: 
(2, 4, 5)
```

for column D2, what proportion of values are greater than 2?  for column D3, what proportion of values are greater than 4, for column D4 (not shown), what proportion of values are greater than D3, and so on...

in this case, it would by 66% (2/3) for D2, and then 33% (1/3) for D3.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to do with D1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
arr = (2, 4, 5)
d = dict(zip(df.drop("D1",1).columns,arr))
pd.Series([df[k].gt(v).sum()/df.shape[0] for k,v in d.items()],index=d.keys())
```

---

```
D2    0.666667
D3    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This answer is the most Pythonic, in my opinion. But, again, thank you all - this very helpful

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is have a for loop go through each value and see if it larger than that number.

```
column_num = 2
more_than_expected = 0
values_total = 0
for val in df["D"+column_num]:
   if val> arr[column_num-2]:
       more_than_expected+=1
   values_total+=1
print(more_than_expected/values_total)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First, you shift the columns:

```
df1 = df[df.columns[1:]]
```

Then you shift the array:

```
ar1 = ar[:-1]
```

Then you subtract one from the other:

```
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: x - ar1, axis=1)
```

Then you can count negative and positive entries to your heart's content:

Comment: Both answers work, but I'm accepting this one for simplicity.  Thank you both for the helpful answers!